# Strange summation transformation

Tags: summation, solution-verification

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADC8Q.png)

If you open the image, you will see two red boxes.

I am expecting there is some changes from the first red box. but there is none.

In the other hand, how to get that second red box from the image?

Should I set n - 1 = 0. -> n = 1. so 1 = n and I just simply replace that part?
By doing so I can get n - I - n just like the image I have posted.
Otherwise, I have no idea how to get that part done.

Comment: $\sum_i (a_i+b_i) = \sum_i a_i + \sum_i b_i\,$, so $\sum_i (n-i-1)$ $=\left(\sum_i n\right)-\left(\sum_i i\right)-\left(\sum_i 1\right)$ $=n(n+1) -\left(\sum_i i\right)-(n+1)\,$. The last term should be $n+1$ (not $n$) because the limits of summation are from $\color{red}{0}$ to $n$.

Comment: The original summation index is from I =0 to n - 1. and they switched to I = 0 to n. I believe there must some transformed during the process?

Comment: There is not enough context to tell that. You should edit the question and fill-in the rest of the blanks. Also, see this [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) primer for posting math.